# Editing the code of a control

Tags: c#, controls, reportviewer, toolbox

Im working with the culture settings of a `Reportviewer` at the moment and no matter what, the report in viewing keeps using my local culture (en-ZA).

- I am not allowed to set the CurrentCulture of the thread(en-ZA)
- I am not allowed to set the culture of the SQL server that the report
  is located on(en-US)

so my only hope is to step into the control itself and do a `ToString()` with its parameters.
to set the format manually.

**QUESTION**

Does anybody know how i can edit the code of a control ?(step into its code and add to it)

Comment: You can do some extension methods like `public static string MeToString(this Reportviewer viewer) { /* process string here */ }` Or eventually read about **CLR injection**

Comment: @m.rogalski hey, anything helps, will do.
Thank you !